# как отправлять запросы GET, POST, синхронные, асинхронные, какие и в каких случаях

Tags: okhttp

Есть телефон-клиент. По вайфай он управляет контроллером и получает данные от АЦП контроллера через модуль ESP8266-сервер. По команде AT+CIFSR с контроллера на модуль ESP8266 можно получить IP этого модуля, он равен 198.168.1.4, номер порта можно произвольно присвоить, например, 8888. Гугл рекомендует OKHTTPclient и даёт рекомендации, как отправлять запросы GET, POST, синхронные, асинхронные. Подключение телефона к модулю я произвожу не в этом приложении, а как обычно, т. к. перед этим командами с контроллера мы задаём режим точки доступа и пароль модулю ESP8266, а потом заходим в наше приложение и работаем. На модуль-сервер с телефона я хочу передать IP, номер порта и несколько байт кода, в битах которого содержится информация о вкл. лазера и т. д. Работаю в андроид студио. Я не могу сообразить, какие запросы GET, POST, синхронные, асинхронные использовать и куда вставить IP модуля-198.168.1.4, номер порта, и пару байт кода, а также откуда взять пришедший код и куда вставить, кроме того, я-клиент периодически должен получать от сервера данные АЦП и отображать в seekbar телефона. Я прошу прощения, может слишком глупые вопросы, я схемотехник, много программировал контроллеров на си, но и в джава и в сетевых протоколах начинающий, хотя и давно пытаюсь разобраться, но в OKHTTPclient немного ориентируюсь, перелопатил много.

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow! Опишите, пожалуйста, подробнее Вашу задачу и распишите пошагово, каким представляете взаимодействие приложения с модулем, а модуля - с внешним миром

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Какие запросы при обмене по OKHTTPclient GET, POST, синхронные, асинхронные исп. и куда вставить IP модуля-198.168.1.4, номер порта, и пару байт кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1260084/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%be-okhttpclient-get-post-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%85%d1%80%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf)